# Session Redis changing every new reload web browser

Tags: php, session, nginx

I have a website with php & nginx. My website uses Symfony 1.4 . My session is stored on Redis.
I have got stuck with session redis .  Every I reload (f5) or open new page then I see that my session value is changed.

Here is my configs for the website:

1/ Redis session storage:
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://10.30.3.15:8875?prefix=PHPREDIS_SESSION_MYSITE:"
2/ My config session in factories

```
storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
        session_name: mysession
        session_cookie_path: /
        session_cookie_lifetime: 2592000 
        session_cookie_httponly: true
        session_cookie_secure: false
```

I write a funtion so that all member must redirect to  login  page when accessing my website without logging in before.

My website use HAPROXY for load balancing.

My problem are to be changed session value in cookie firebug and some time I was be logout ( redirect to login page).

Please help me fix this problem.

Thanks & Best regards,

David Abbala.

Comment: Here is my HaProxy config:      # [HTTP Site Configuration] :
    listen  http_web *:80 :
     mode http :
     balance roundrobin  # Load Balancing algorithm
  #balance leastconn
  #option httpchk
  option forwardfor
  #option abortonclose
  option httpclose
  server server3 10.30.3.18:8086 weight 1 maxconn 500000 check
  server server4 10.30.3.19:8086 weight 1 maxconn 500000 check
  #server server1 10.30.3.14:8086 weight 1 maxconn 500000 check
  server server2 10.30.3.15:8086 weight 1 maxconn 500000 check